# How are Data Science And Cryptography releated

Tags: cryptography, data-analysis

Is there any interesting connections between Data Science And Cryptography. Data Science involves using Statistical Analysis to analyze data, while Cryptography also involves Statistics in cryptanalysis in order to protect data. And of course both fields require a lot of math. So, I wonder if there is any interesting links between these two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the classical cryptography has not. If you mean machine learning when it comes to data science, the newer method ''learning with errors'' is has some relationship. The latter method is thought to be secure against quantum attacks and so belongs to the post-quantum cryptography.